# CSS - Create gap between borders?

Tags: css

**Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8t6g6jeq/1/**

So I thought I'd be able to achieve this with a margin.  Borders don't seem to be applied to top margins but they do apply to bottom margins?  That's how it seems, and I've added padding to thicken out the clickable area while keeping the element centered .

```
margin: 5px 0; 
padding: 10px 0;
```

It's hard to describe what I want my outcome so I've drawn this in paint:
[image]

I'm flustered and almost embarrassed that I can't do this... Any help would be great.

Thanks!

*Edit - After applying a border-top to my spans it seems like the same goes for top margins too.

Comment: do you really like the arrangement of your `<span>`s and want an answer with your spans in it? Or would a solution with a one or two extra divs and spans added on top of your current html be okay? (It would make the css soooooo much cleaner and smaller)

Comment: @cake I'm targeting the spans as they are in jQuery, but I'm open to changing it if it'll work :)

Comment: _“Borders don't seem to be applied to top margins but they do apply to bottom margins?”_ – that question just makes no sense. Borders are applied to _elements_, not “to margins”.

Comment: @CBroe it completely makes sense what she's asking. The correct answer is that borders are applied INSIDE of the margins, OUTSIDE of padding.

Comment: To me it doesn’t. _“borders are applied INSIDE of the margins, OUTSIDE of padding”_ – that is of course true (and OP could have easily looked that up on their own), but phrasing that as “borders are _applied to_ margins” is still nonsense IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe ah okay yeah, I agree with you

Answer (score 2):

you could simulate a border with a empty element with :after

```
#nav span:after{
   content: '';
   background: black;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 5px; 
   width: 2px;
   height: 20px;
   right: -10px;    
}
```

very rough draft: http://jsfiddle.net/8t6g6jeq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use after and apply the changes, refer this solution

http://jsbin.com/valufajina/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that the order of the visual output is:
 - margin on the outside
 - the border is on the inside
 - the padding is inside of the border

so no matter how much margin you add - the borders will not change. Margins are *outside* of borders. And as for padding ... it will not allow you to specify the area between the two edges of a border.

The only way I can think of solving this is by adding another container to your code. That way you can define borders for the two different items, and have space between the borders. It also makes the CSS veryyyy clean and small.

I've modified your fiddle to contain the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div>
        <span class="active">Nav Item</span>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
        <span>Nav Item</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;    }

#nav div {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;     }

#nav span {
    color: #D3D3D3; 
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font: normal 13px arial;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 145px;    }

#nav div span:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;    }

#nav span:hover, #trendNav span.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;    }
```

[image: js fiddle result]